# frequency modulation and incoming signal selection

Tags: modulation, signal-processing

I have some understanding of what frequency modulation entails - it entails "adding" a new frequency to the frequency spectrum of a signal. But how, exactly, is a modulated signal selected in the receiver? Say you're listening to your car radio and want the radio signal modulated at 80 Hz or something. How does the actual system select it? In general, not in car radios specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, realize that all forms of modulation add frequencies to that of the carrier.  These frequencies appear close to the carrier so that the modulated signal can be selected with a bandpass filter.  You do this by tuning the radio to a specific station. Then the signal from the selected station is demodulated. For amplitude modulation, a detector sensitive to amplitude variations is used.  For frequency modulation, a detector sensitive to frequency variations is used. This is a greatly simplified explanation.  For details, you need to look in any communications textbook or search the internet.

Answer (score 1):

A radio receiver does not just receive a single frequency, but receives a narrow band of frequencies.

That is, a receiver tuned to 1000 kHz does not reject frequencies of 999.999 kHz and below, and frequencies of 1000.001 kHz and above.  Instead, it will receive all frequencies between 990 kHz and 1010 kHz equally well.  This allows the sidebands added by the modulation to pass through the RF and IF stages of the receiver to reach the demodulator.